# stop iPhone offloading downloaded music

Tags: iphone

Music doesn't show up in Settings > Apple ID > iCloud, so I can't uncheck the checkbox there.

I want the music i download to my phone to stay on my phone.

How can I

1. re-download all the music that has already been clouded
2. force it and all future music to stay there

Comment: Which checkbox are you referring to? And Music has its own top-level entry in Settings (scroll down)

Comment: @nohillside in the iCloud section of settings, you can turn off sync. I saw it here <https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/353775/150109>

Comment: This refers to iBooks. You are talking about Music.

Comment: @nohillside that's why the checkbox doesn't exist. I only explained I looked where I have looked for similar options before, and the option didn't exist in that location.

Comment: It doesn’t exist because it is in the Music section. And it still doesn‘t explain which checkbox you look for.

Comment: @nohillside I looked for a "Music" toggle in Settings > Apple ID > iCloud. There isn't one there.

Comment: @nohillside i also can't see any relevant toggle in Settings > Music

Comment: As I said: Music settings are not within the iCloud part (because Music isn‘t part of iCloud), not finding them there is to be expected and not a problem as such.

Comment: @nohillside okay. How do I stop Music from offloading songs I have downloaded onto my phone?